# Django admin GenericForeignKey inline

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    ...
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to={"model__in": ("agentprofile", "clientprofile"))
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    profile = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class AgentProfile(models.Model):
    license_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)

class ClientProfile(models.Model):
    address = models.CHarField(max_length=250)
```

I have 3 models: MyUser(custom user model), ClientProfile, AgentProfile. How can I edit ClientProfile/AgentProfile on MyUser admin page (like inline)?

Comment: Please show your models and explain what do you mean by `inline`?

Comment: @alecxe I have two different type of users (agents and clients). I want to edit MyUser model and profile on the single page.

Answer (score 26):

You need to use GenericTabularInline. See the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#using-generic-relations-as-an-inline).